# Taking JSON and working with individuals pieces of information within the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an Express App that is being fed JSON data, when I req.body the data I get this:

```
{ '["A","07 Sep 2016","47.07","47.17","46.86","47.11","1542500"]': '' }
```

In the end I need to get this into my RethinkDB database, but right now I am trying to just console.log the "A" I have tried req.body[0] and it is showing undefined. I am a little confused about the fact that there are ' ' around the array. I am not sure where the : '' comes from at the end of the JSON but for now I just need the main values in the array.

FYI I am using papaParse to parse a CSV to JSON which is how this data is being sent to my express app. Then fetch is being used to send the data with 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' as the header.

Comment: Could you provide CSV data? It's hard to tell which data you really want to extract.

Comment: That array is the _key_ and the value for it is an empty string. It seems like the data is not passed in correctly.

Comment: You'll probably want application/json as the content type, but if you really want to send it as a non json form then using a constant field name and your string as the value would be more typical and easier to process.

Comment: Oh I see what your saying, there is no value! I get that now. So I have more work to do with PapaParse to get it to parse correctly. One issue I have is that there are no headers in these CSVs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is structured differently then you think.

Your JSON:

```
{
  '["A","07 Sep 2016","47.07","47.17","46.86","47.11","1542500"]': ''
}
```

so req.body[0] wont work, the key is the array which is what you need and the value is just an empty string.

should be something like this:

```
{
  'result': '["A","07 Sep 2016","47.07","47.17","46.86","47.11","1542500"]'
}

req.body.result[0] // -> "A"
```

Comment: You can do a for in loop over req.body and access the key. Or you can send back the response differently

Comment: I am using PapaParse to parse the data and looking in Chrome Dev Tools I see what is being passed to the server is just an array, its actually not an object at all. So I think the issue is with Express and bodyParser. Thanks I'll post another question.